# what if I mount a logical volume on a local directory where restore MySQL data and the process is still running?

Tags: linux

Here is the detailed description:

1. `/data` is a local directory, I extracted MySQl binary package here, then configured and started it. The `basedir` and `datadir` were both subdirectories under `/data`

```
basedir=/data/mysql 

datadir=/data/mysql/data
```

2. The `mysqld` process is running without error. Now I create a logical volume: `/dev/mapper/vg-lvdata`, then I mount it on `/data`.

Here, I do not stop `mysqld` process, but mount the LV directly.

3. Result:

As we all know, when we mount a device to a local directory, then we change directory to it, we will find there are no data in it. The original data is in local.

But the result makes me curious,`mysqld` service is still running, and the new data is writing to local directory.

#### Question:

Can anyone tell the reason of this?

Why `mysqld` service can still read and write data to local directory?

Answer (score 1):

For the same reason that it will keep working (until you restart it) if you just delete random files out of that data directory.

Put simply, once you open a file on a system with POSIX VFS semantics, you have an open file descriptor for *that* file.  Until you close that file, you can continue to access it no matter what else happens to it (short of hardware failures causing I/O errors).  Someone else (or you) can delete that file, and you'll still be able to access it (the space it occupies will be automatically freed when the last open file descriptor for it is closed, this is often used for secure temporary files).  The permissions can change such that you wouldn't be able to open it, and you'll still be able to access it.  The file can be *moved*, and the open file descriptor will just follow it.

Note, however, that this requires that you actually keep open references to files you're using instead of opening them each time you want to access them.  Most system services are smart enough to keep such open references, but most interactive software (for example, your shell process) is not, and will immediately notice that the directory contents have changed.